# Why doesn't this javascript closure work as I hoped?

Tags: javascript, widget, closures

I wrote this piece of code, hoping that after running the `document.ready()` part the `widget_controller` property on `search_form.widget_date_range` object will become a controller. To my surprise, it is `undefined`. What is going wrong here?

```
search_form.widget_date_range = (function() {
  var element_selector = "div.date-range-slider";
  var settings = {
    bounds: {
      min: new Date(2003, 0, 1),
      max: new Date()
    },
    defaultValues: {
      min: new Date(2003, 0, 1),
      max: new Date()
    },
    wheelMode: "zoom",
  };
  var widget_controller = {};
  var onDocumentReady = function() {
    widget_controller = $(element_selector).dateRangeSlider(settings);
    widget_controller.on("valuesChanged", onDataChange);
    console.log(widget_controller);
  };
  var onDataChange = function(e, data) {
    // alert("Value just changed. min: " + data.values.min + " max: " + data.values.max);
    $("form#searching").trigger("submit");
  };
  return {
    onDocumentReady: onDocumentReady,
    widget_controller: widget_controller
  };
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    search_form.widget_date_range.onDocumentReady();
});
```

Comment: Your onDocumentReady() function isn't being called? Is that what is happening?

Comment: Does search_form have a value before you try to write the widget_date_range property to it?

This could be a sign of variable hoisting. Are you declaring "var search_form" anywhere in your ready function?

Comment: @Marcos. Thanks Marcos, yes I called it from document.ready at the bottom.

Comment: @JohnKossa: Yes the search_form is a returned object from another self-invoking function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a point about references in JavaScript:

```
var search_form={};
search_form.widget_date_range = (function() {
   // Whatever code here

  // widget_controller variable references an empty object
  var widget_controller = {}; // #A
  var onDocumentReady = function() {
    // Here you redefine widget_controller,
    // but not the returned_object.widget_controller property
    widget_controller = $(element_selector).dateRangeSlider(settings); #B
    widget_controller.on("valuesChanged", onDataChange);
    console.log(widget_controller);
  };
  // Whatever here
  return {
    onDocumentReady: onDocumentReady,
    // returned_objet.widget_controller references the empty object
    widget_controller: widget_controller #C
  };
})();
```

One solution could be:

```
  ...
  return {
    onDocumentReady: onDocumentReady,
    get widget_controller() {
      return widget_controller; #D
    }
  };
  ...
```

JSFiddle demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/xgya3mzh/2/

**EDIT: (it seems like more explanation are required)**

First : 
the `{ get property() {} }` syntax is from ES5 and you can find doc on MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

You could accomplish the same with ES3 with another syntax, explained here: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/**defineGetter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__) (but use this syntax only if you wish to support IE8 and below - I hope you don't have to).

At `#A` you declare the variable widget_controller and set it to an (almost) empty object (`{}`); (I say almost because it still has a prototype with some inherited methods and properties).

At `#C` you set the property `widget_controller` of an object literal (which will be returned by the closure) to the reference of the empty object.

At `#B`, which happens **after** `#C`, you redefine widget_controller of the closure, but you don't redefine the widget_controller of the object returned by the function, which still references the value of the empty object.

In my code, in `#D`, the same widget_controller of the closure is returned whenever you access the property widget_controller of the object returned by the closure.

I hope it is clearer, though I am not very sure...

Comment: My goodness, it works! What exactly wrong with my version, dear laruiss? Isn't it a typical closure, and the widget_controller inside my onDocumentReady function should reference its immediate outer scope, which defines the widget_controller to an empty object {}? Why does it have to redefine it again? I'm scratching my head right now.

Comment: Also, could you please give a clue on how that "get widget_controller()" part works? I've tried googling it but didn't find anything relevant. Many thanks.

Comment: Could someone please explain a little clue on why my first version doesn't work? It seems to be a perfect closure to me. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I edited my answer to add some explanation. I hope you understand better. If not, don't hesitate to say so.

Comment: @Iaruiss: It's very clear now. And thank you very much for your detailed and thorough explanations. I really enjoy reading it!